# GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder callback with empty changes the first time

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have setup Cosmos and a change feed according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-change-feed-start-time).

[`GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getchangefeedprocessorbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) calls the `onChangesDelegate` with an empty changes collection the first time
Next time it is populated.

Why is the first callback empty? I see no reason or documentation for this.

---

```
changeFeedProcessor = cosmosClient.GetContainer(myOptions, myCollection)
    .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<MyEntity>("MyProcessorName", HandleChangesAsync)
    .WithLeaseConfiguration()
    .WithInstanceName("MyInstanceName")
    .WithLeaseContainer(myLeaseContainer)
    .WithStartTime(System.DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime()))
.Build();
```

and

```
private async Task HandleChangesAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<ArticleEntity> changes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    // here `changes` is of 0 length, first time
```

Comment: Can you specify which SDK version you are using?

Comment: Dotnet Core 2.2(.5?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to repro and sent a PR with the fix, please follow it if you want to be aware of the resolution: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/756